# Cannot override "preferredDisplayMode" in SplitView

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I have an app with multiple UISplitViewControllers that each have their own MasterView and DetailView. I noticed, however, that when I launch right into one of the SplitViews, I get presented with the DetailView, and have to navigate back to the MasterView first. I would like to change that, and found out that this works with the `preferredDisplayMode`, but setting it somehow causes problems.

I've create a subclass of UISplitViewController for all three SplitViews, and tried overriding the `preferredDisplayMode` like this:

```
import UIKit

internal class SplitViewController : UISplitViewController {

    @IBAction internal func unwindToSplitView(segue: UIStoryboardSegue)

    override let preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.PrimaryOverlay
}
```

However, I get the following error:

> Cannot override with a stored property 'preferredDisplayMode'

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instead override the func `viewDidLoad()` and set `preferredDisplayMode` to the value that you want in there. Like so:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    preferredDisplayMode = .PrimaryOverlay // Or UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.PrimaryOverlay if you prefer (both are equivalent)
}
```